# import error: python for 3.7 but no error in 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, lxml, python-3.7

when I type python
<< import lxml
it does not give an error but when I type python3
<< import lxml
it gives an error saying no module named 'lxml'

how can I solve this problem

Comment: By installing `lmxl` in 3.7. At a _guess_: `pip3 install lxml`

Comment: Python modules are usually installed *per Python binary*, you need to install lxml for your Python 3.7 binary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you haven't installed the module under Python3.  In most cases, you merely need to use the Python3 installer on the package, such as

```
pip3 install lxml
```

[Installation guide](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html).
See the section near the bottom on working with multiple Python versions.